# Append dynamic timestamp at the start of command output

Tags: bash

I wanted to check with `bash` community if its possible to print dynamic timestamp before each line of command output, even the command itself take sometime to print the entire result. Here is example:

Here , for sake of explanation assume `(echo hi; sleep 10; echo hello)` as a single CLI command. It will print the entire result in ~10 seconds(this could varies) which comprises of multiple line output, note the output below . Every line is having exact timestamp when the line is printed to the screen.

```
(echo hi ;sleep 10 ;echo hello) |perl -nle 'print scalar(localtime), " ", $_'
Mon Oct 15 13:15:57 2018 hi
Mon Oct 15 13:16:07 2018 hello
```

Query:

So, my question: Is is possible to manipulate `bashrc` or any other configuration in such a way that this will become default behavior without using `pipe` and perl command manually on each command  ?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping programmers solve their programming code problems. This Q is off topic here, but may be more appropriate on https://superuser.com OR https://unix.stackexchange.com .Also, updating prompts has been covered here and the other forums before, did you try searching? Please read the [help] and [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Hello Shelter, I have my `PS1` updated with time ,In this scenario I needed timestamp printed for each line of the command output. Although , can you please help to migrate this question to superuser.com or later ?

Comment: I don't think what you describe is possible without writing your own script that parses the command line for each `;` delimited segment and issues a `date` command before the first cmd and then after each command is completed. This will be difficult to get right for command commands (like `cmd|grep srchTarg`), etc. Once you get that script working, then you can think about how to integrate it into the `prompt` processing of your shell (which I don't think will be possible, maybe in `zsh`). This seems like a beginners mistake in over optimizing  a problem. Keep it simple! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, I replaced your `perl` command by `ts`.
The following trick is not a full solution, but you may be interested anyway.

Start `bash | ts` manually, in the new shell all command outputs will be timestamped. Example of such an interactive session:

```
$ echo test
test
$ bash | ts
$ echo test
Oct 16 13:40:16 test
$ for i in a b c; do echo "$i"; sleep 1; done
Oct 16 13:41:38 a
Oct 16 13:41:39 b
Oct 16 13:41:40 c
$ exit
Oct 16 13:41:51
$ echo test
test
```

However, text interfaces like that of `nano` do not seem to work anymore when inside `bash | ts`. Also clearing the scroll buffer with `printf '\033c'` doesn't work anymore.

The following command will start `bash | ts` from within your `.bashrc`. Paste it at the very end of `.bashrc`. I wouldn't recommend it because of the mentioned problems.

```
bashParents="$(ps | grep -Fwc bash)"
(( bashParents-- )) # because of subshell $(...)
if (( bashParents <= 1 )); then
    bash | ts
fi
```

Comment: `ts` ... very nice! Thanks for sharing. I hope it helps @monk. Good luck to all.

Comment: thank you , I put my code in `.bash_profile` its working as I am expecting